# create soap request xml in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to consume a service .

Can any one help me how to generate a soap request as follows.

i want to construct a class and then serialize the class using soap formator and then post it to my service. I tried with the some online help but could not able to generate the required soap xml.

i am bit confused about the implementation .Can any one help me on this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:iot="http://services.singp.com>
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <iot.performService>
         <iot.input>
            <iot.gsh><![CDATA[
            <header xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://services.singp.com">
                <GUID></GUID>
                <CustID></CustID>
                <RequestName></RequestName>
                <TimeStamp>2017-06-09T10:49:03.49-05:00</TimeStamp>
            </header>
            ]]></iot.gsh>
            <iot.Body><![CDATA[
            <CustStatus xmlns="http://services.singp.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                 <CustStatusAttributes>
                    <CustID>str1234</CustID>
                    <Action>str1234</Action>
                 </CustStatusAttributes>
                <CustStatusInformation>
                    <ClientOrderNumber>745</ClientOrderNumber>
                </CustStatusInformation>
            </CustStatus>

            ]]></iot.Body>
         </iot.input>
      </iot.performService>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Do you really require to create the soap message yourself? Usually you'd only add a Service Reference and have the proxy classes generated for you.

Comment: Don't roll the message by hand, use WCF instead

Comment: i am consuming a soap service.today i have to consume 4 services tomorrow 6 more services have to be consumed , so i am planning to use httpwebrequest , 

i dont want to creat a proxy and calling the service, i want to use httpwebRequest. based on a service and i want to generate the soap reequest dynamically and call the service.

for each new service i will create a separate project which will be implement the base class /interface using a unity application block.